# MySQL dump only has SET commands, no data

Tags: mysql, export

I've done an export of a Wordpress database. The MySQL file that was exported only contains the Host, Database name, server version and SET commands.

Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/pFgdPDRa

Another strange thing is the line at the end of the export:
-- Dump completed on 2013-02-14  9:38:34

The export was done in early 2016, so I'm not sure what that's about?

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't have the data, and it contains an old timestamp – perhaps it's not the dump you are looking for?

Comment: Perhaps the dump was taken with the `--no-data` option?